# How to properly create pandas DataFrame from a list: all columns are merged in a single column "0"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
print("body['csvData']", body['csvData'])

print("===============================")

csvData = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in str(body['csvData']).split('\n')])

print("TYPE csvData", type(csvData))

print(csvData.head())
```

It receives the content of the POST body request from React.js and tries to convert `csvData` into pandas DataFrame.

I get this output:

```
body['csvData']
 NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TURNAROUND,DISTANCE_FROM_ORIGIN,DISTANCE_TO_TARGET
1,AEA,H,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,605,9920.67,5776.89
2,AEA,H,2016-01-01 04:25:00,2016-01-01 06:30:00,125.0,10060.80,483.93
3,AVA,H,2016-01-01 05:05:00,2016-01-01 07:05:00,120.0,8033.86,8033.86
4,IBE,H,2016-01-01 05:20:00,2016-01-01 10:40:00,320.0,6000.00,8507.73
5,IBE,H,2016-01-01 05:25:00,2016-01-01 10:50:00,325.0,6698.42,6698.42

===============================
TYPE csvData <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
                                                0
0  NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TU...
1,AEA,H,2016-01-01 04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:0...
2,AEA,H,2016-01-01 04:25:00,2016-01-01 06:30:0... 
3,AVA,H,2016-01-01 05:05:00,2016-01-01 07:05:0... 
4,IBE,H,2016-01-01 05:20:00,2016-01-01 10:40:0...
```

It looks like `csvData` is converted into pandas DataFrame, however all columns are merged into a single column called `0`.

```
print(csvData.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
0    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you please share body['csvData']? And how you get it into python?

Comment: @Fatih1923: Thanks for your quick response. The `body['csvData']` is shown before `===============================` in my post. I get it as follows in Django: `body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')` and then `body = json.loads(body_unicode)`

Comment: Have tried to get it by `pd.read_csv() `? Another question is why you split lines by semicolon. Your data were separated by comma.

Comment: @Fatih1923: 1) You are right. I substituted semicolons by commas and now columns are split, but the first row is not a header. The header is generated from numbers 0, 1, 2, .... I need to have the first row as a header. 2) Yes, I tried `pd.read_csv(str(body["csvData"]))`, but then I get an error `FileNotFoundError: File b'NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TURNAROUND,DISTANCE_FROM_ORIGIN,DISTANCE_TO_TARGET\n1,AEA,H,2016-01-01 04:05:00...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_csv()` needs tte location of csv file. You should now add the codes given below.

```
csvData.columns = csvData.iloc[0]
csvData.reindex(csvData.index.drop(0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that it should be iloc[0] and drop(0)?

Comment: I see that one more row (the last one) appeared `21               None                 None`.